# Why can't I complete getaway car on gta v xbox one?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I got a car, put it in position,called Michael and confirmed the location but can't start Blitz Play and when I go to replay missions getaway car is not there?

Comment: Getaway Vehicle is not replayable and has no medal objectives. Have you definitely done all the setup missions for Blitz Play?

Comment: 100% i checked the list on some guide online

Comment: Did you do the first Lester assassination mission as Franklin yet?

Comment: No is that necessary?

Comment: Just did it and unlocked the H mission. Thanks bro :)